# Terminal doesn't launch in vscode even after adding path to cwd

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, terminal

Terminal doesn't launch in vscode. Shows error as tries to open previous file path. I have changed to desired path in cwd, still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the path: "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\application2\PS D:\udemy web-dev\application" from your workspace and add a new workspace: "D:\udemy web-dev\application".

See a test directory that I had to remove as shown in the image below.

[image: WORKSPACE SCREENSHOT]

Else if you do not add a workspace and run a new terminal it will default to the directory you set in cwd.

[image: New Terminal Screenshot]